# Dockerfile installs node but getting "/bin/bash: node: command not found" error

Tags: node.js, bash, docker, npm, nvm

I have a Dockerfile that switches users for package installation

```
FROM private_registry

# Use root to install packages and create tmp dir
USER root
WORKDIR /tmp

RUN yum -y install gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel make && yum clean all

# Configure NodeJS
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.5/install.sh | bash \
    && [ -s ~/.nvm/nvm.sh ] && \. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh \
    && [ -s ~/.nvm/bash_completion ] && \. ~/.nvm/bash_completion \
    && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION} \
    && npm install --global yarn \
    && npm cache clean --force \ 
    && mv ~/.nvm /opt/nvm \
    && ln -s /opt/nvm/.nvm/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin/npm /bin/npm \
    && cat ~/.bashrc

...

# Switch to user1
USER user1
WORKDIR /home/user1

# Add node to PATH
ENV NODE_HOME /opt/nvm/.nvm
ENV PATH ${NODE_HOME}/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

RUN echo "umask 022" >> .bashrc
```

When I docker run and test my installed packages, I am getting:
`/bin/bash: node: command not found`. What am I missing or not understanding? Ideally I keep the installation method the same, just make the required changes.

I have read posts about configuring .bashrc so bash can pick up node command, however not sure how that applies here...

Comment: The build-time `ENV PATH` does not, and could not, affect the final image. Add that to your `.bashrc` too (or install the binary somewhere sensible in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be using NVM inside a container. You're not managing any node versions in the container itself. Node should be installed once and ideally managed from the Dockerfile. A container is not meant to be changed as all changes will be lost when recreating the container (unless you're mounting the path with node installed, which is a totally different issue and also should be avoided as far as possible). I understand that NVM is recommended but this is not the case within a container.

If you really want to curl a package instead of using the distro's package manager, see how it's done in the official node container [here](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node). There are Dockerfile templates for debian and alpine in the above link but I'm sure you can adapt the installation for your distro of choice (I see you're using yum so assuming centos or a RHEL fork).

I cannot speak for the use of NVM in a container as I have not tried it but if you must, try adding this to your `user1` .bashrc (it is needed as you are configuring node using `root` but running the application using `user1` i.e nvm was not properly set up for `user1`).

`source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`